# Look for gem "dynamime" with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

is there any BrowserDetection-Mobile gem like https://github.com/wvk/dynamime for Rails 3?
unfortunately dynamime doenst work with Rails 3 and is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

You could mobile-fu it's Rails 3 compatible https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu

Comment: mobile-fu is great. But it doesnt provide that much information about the device (the WURFL Part is missing)